# Slower site with the *same* configuration than a mirror copy... how is that possible?

Tags: performance, webserver

I´ve got this Drupal site (ligadelconsorcista.org) that I have to move it from one server to another. The reason was that my older host even when it was pretty decent, it started a couple of months now to have many short downtimes, wich drove me crazy.
The thing is that I´ve made a sort of mirror copy of the site: I´ve copied all the files exactly the same, and after that I´ve imported the database.

The problem is that the new site connects much slower than my old hosting! (the new one is mediatemple) I´ve contacted their support and they tell me that there are several factors that can contribute to that... but that has nothing to do with their hosting service.

**The thing is that I don´t even know where to start looking for the problem.**

Notes: 
The new configuration is the same that the one I had with the older hosting account.
Today I´ve set an account with cloudflare´s CDN to try to solve the problem. Even if the CDN is configured ok (I´ve asked their help desk) it won´t add any performance improvement.

Any clues of what may I do about this?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just add a static page on the new hosting, is the response slow or fast? Just want to isolate the problem.

And also, is there any difference between the php and mysql version of old and new hosting?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just found that the problem was... the new hosting. Change again to other one and... voilá! I think it was because their database wasn´t in localhost, but in other server, so it was a slower way to get to the data.